# Swift: Constant in Template Definition

Tags: ios, swift, decodable, jsondecoder

I'm working with a backend developer that likes to encapsulate json bodies in another object such as data:

Example:

> GET: /user/current:

```
{
  data: {
          firstName: "Evan",
          lastName: "Stoddard"
        }
}
```

I would simply like to just call json decode on the response to get a User struct that I've created but the added data object requires another struct.  To get around this I created a generic template class:

```
struct DecodableData<DecodableType:Decodable>:Decodable {

    var data:DecodableType

}
```

Now I can get my json payload and if I want to get a User struct just get the data property of my template:

```
let user = JSONDecoder().decode(DecodableData<User>.self, from: jsonData).data
```

This is all fine and dandy until sometimes, the key, `data`, isn't always `data`.

I feel like this is most likely fairly trivial stuff, but is there a way I can add a parameter in my template definition so I can change the enum coding keys as that data key might change?

Something like the following?

```
struct DecodableData<DecodableType:Decodable, Key:String>:Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = Key
    }

    var data:DecodableType

}
```

This way I can pass in the target decodable class along with the key that encapsulates that object.

Comment: Please look at the error you get: *Raw value for enum case must be a literal*.

Comment: Do you always know at compile time what the key will be, or do you only find out at run time?

Comment: @vadian I'm aware of the error hence why I asked the question.

Comment: @robmayoff I would know at compilation time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for coding keys. Instead, you need a simple container that parses the JSON as a dictionary that has exactly one key-value pair, discarding the key.

```
struct Container<T>: Decodable where T: Decodable {
    let value: T

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dict = try container.decode([String: T].self)

        guard dict.count == 1 else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "expected exactly 1 key value pair, got \(dict.count)")
        }

        value = dict.first!.value
    }
}
```

If the JSON is empty or has more than one key-value pair, an exception is raised.

Assuming a simple struct such as

```
struct Foo: Decodable, Equatable {
    let a: Int
}
```

you can parse it regardless of the key:

```
let foo1 = try! JSONDecoder().decode(
    Container<Foo>.self,
    from: #"{ "data": { "a": 1 } }"#.data(using: .utf8)!
).value

let foo2 = try! JSONDecoder().decode(
    Container<Foo>.self,
    from: #"{ "doesn't matter at all": { "a": 1 } }"#.data(using: .utf8)!
).value

foo1 == foo2 // true
```

This also works for JSON responses that have `null` as the value, in which case you need to parse it as an optional of your type:

```
let foo = try! JSONDecoder().decode(
    Container<Foo?>.self,
    from: #"{ "data": null }"#.data(using: .utf8)!
).value // nil
```

Comment: What if his structure wrapper get another property?

Comment: @iDevid that's a completely different problem. If you have more than one property, the key is no longer irrelevant, in which case a typical `struct` with the relevant keys is the way to go. BTW, did you downvote me to promote your answer?

Comment: Nope, because the problem was that "I feel like this is most likely fairly trivial stuff, but is there a way I can add a parameter in my template definition so I can change the enum coding keys as that data key might change?"
I think your solution works well if the wrapper contains one property, instead, if become to got bigger (with errors, and statuses) it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
struct GenericCodingKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String

    init(value: String) {
        self.stringValue = value
    }

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int?

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }
}

struct DecodableData<DecodableType: CustomDecodable>: Decodable {

    var data: DecodableType

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: GenericCodingKey.self)
        data = try container.decode(DecodableType.self, forKey: GenericCodingKey(value: DecodableType.dataKey))
    }
}

protocol CustomDecodable: Decodable {
    static var dataKey: String { get }
}

extension CustomDecodable {
    static var dataKey: String {
        return "data" // This is your default
    }
}


struct CustomDataKeyStruct: CustomDecodable {
    static var dataKey: String = "different"
}

struct NormalDataKeyStruct: CustomDecodable {
    //Change Nothing
}
```